# DNS Server Mac OS X 10.6 DNS Zone FIle

Tags: domain-name-system

Does anyone see a problem with this zone file:

```
$TTL 10800
poweranew.biz. IN SOA server.poweranew.biz. chrismuench.poweranew.biz (
        2011031802      ;Serial
        86400           ;Refresh
        3600            ;Retry
        604800          ;Expire
        345600          ;Negative caching TTL
 )

poweranew.biz. IN  NS server.poweranew.biz.
server IN  A 192.168.1.3
poweranew.biz. IN  A 192.168.1.3
```

I am not very familiar with DNS and had a problem where I could not access poweranew.biz within my own server so I added an A record for it which fixed the problem. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one "error" that I see there is that the email address is using a relative path; so it would resolve as `chrismuench.poweranew.biz.poweranew.biz`.  Add a trailing dot to fix.

Beyond that, if you're so inclined it would keep it a bit more readable as more records are added if you were to use relative pathing instead of absolute in some spots:

```
$TTL 10800
@       IN      SOA     server.poweranew.biz. chrismuench.poweranew.biz. (
        2011031802      ;Serial
        86400           ;Refresh
        3600            ;Retry
        604800          ;Expire
        345600          ;Negative caching TTL
 )

@       IN      NS      server.poweranew.biz.
@       IN      A       192.168.1.3

server  IN      A       192.168.1.3
```